# AJAX Security Issue

Tags: ajax

I'm really new to AJAX. And I saw this tutorial about how to retrieve database result using ajax
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp

Source Code from the URL :

```
<script>
function showUser(str)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
  return;
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Is that code secure enough?
Any other concerns that I need to check other than server side validation for the security?
What is the best practice regarding the security to apply that code?

Thanks and I'm really sorry for the dumb question. T_T

Comment: Bad resources always causes problems I mean please dont use w3school

Comment: The PHP code in the article is using depreciated `mysql_*` functions *and* is completely vulnerable to SQL injection. The clientside code isn't going to affect serverside security (which is non-existent in that example code), but you should watch out for XSS attacks and properly sanitize all user input.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not using that mysql_ anymore. And I just learned about this AJAX. Btw, Do I really need to encrypt that 'str' in javascript with something and then decrypt it in php for additional security?

Answer (score 1):

The 'secure enough' part depends on what you do on the server side. At the client, there is a missing part here the "str" value is encoded as proper URL value and hence this could cause some problems.

You should at least use the `encodeURIComponent` (or `escape`) method when concatenating url parts.

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+encodeURIComponent(str),true);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I assume this encodeURIComponent is the same as urlencode() in php right?

Comment: Yes, it is quite similar, see the docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent